# html5 media tag change with change of media type in playlist

Tags: html5-video, playlists

I am having a requirement of creating a playlist of selected media(both audio and video) from local machine using HTML5 media tags. I am using the below code

http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio

Now the problem am facing is in this line
        extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';

it only plays audio files if i change it to video/mp4 it plays  video files only if i use if else then also the first condition is working

```
                if(audio.canPlayType('video/mp4')) {
                extension = '.mp4';
                }
                else if
                (audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')) {
            extension = '.mp3';
            }
```

Please help me out what could be the condition I can put here to play both type of media in playlist and also if possible I can switch video/audio tag with the type of media selected.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use both video and audio in a playlist you should use the html5 video tag instead of the audio tag. You do not need to switch back and forth. The video tag will play both audio and video files.

In order to use the code from the site listed, you will need to know whether you are loading a video or an audio file. Then you can determine the correct extension to use based on browser support found in the script. See the new html5 video and audio playlist example below:

http://jonhall.info/examples/html5_video_audio_playlist_example.html

In the new example I replaced the code:

```
extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
```

with a function:

```
getExtension = function(type) {
    extension = '';
    if(type === 'a') {
        if(video.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')) {
            extension = '.mp3';
        }
        if(video.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) {
            extension = '.ogg';
        }
    }
    if(type === 'v') {
        if(video.canPlayType('video/mp4')) {
            extension = '.mp4';
        }
        if(video.canPlayType('video/ogg')) {
            extension = '.ogv';
        }
    }
    return extension;
};
```

Pass the letter `'a'` for audio or the letter `'v'` for video.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, but as i need to create a playlist i have to select media from local storage and then pass it to list to play in order , i cant able to figure out how to pass those files as JSON to the list, so I was trying some other way, if you can help me out in passing the JSON to a list and then follow the above script to play the medias, that would be quite helpful to me.Thanks again